# PHP Array is getting Consumed

Tags: php, arrays, generics, garbage-collection

I had that weird thing using arrays in PHP.

```
$items = array();
$tools = json_decode($_GET['tools'],true);
foreach($tools as $key => $value)
{
   $items[$somevar][$anothervar] = $value;
}
```

Then I could iterate `$items`

```
foreach($items as $key => $value)
{
  //Do Something
}
```

But the weird part is, when I tried again to iterate through `$tools` with `foreach`, it returns `NULL`.

```
//Never Happens    
foreach($tools as $key => $value)
{
  //Do Something
}
```

Could this be caused by the Garbage Collector?

My app is running with PHP 5.2.3, Linux CentOS, Apache 2.2.

Comment: Middle code block does not contain $items. Error?

Comment: Could you give more code specially between both foreach'es?

Comment: @neworld there's only some HTML between these Portions

Comment: [It works for me](http://viper-7.com/mH1ar2).

Comment: @Cody Try post the whole code, and post the result of var_dump($tools).

Comment: What exactly returns NULL? The $value is set to null?

Comment: @Cody: it is a possibility you need to [reset array iteration](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) but I am not sure.

Comment: @neworld internal pointer of the array is reset on the beginning of every foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I doubt that this has to do with the garbage collection.

The garbage collector only removes a `zval` (a PHP variable container) if the `refcount` is zero. This means, only if no variable-reference points to the data, it will get removed.

As long as you don't do an `unset( $tools );`, the variable should be available.

See http://php.net/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php for details.

Answer (score 0):

`$tools` is not an array, it's an object.

change it to this:

```
$tools = json_decode($_GET['tools'], true);
```

the `true` argument decodes the json into an array instead of an object.

More here: [PHP Documantation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Sory ,i mistyped the question see EDITS

Comment: still, you should add the true

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's not an array, so it's work like that  :

```
$tools->key // Return the value of your occurence
```

Comment: Trying to access an array like that would issue a notice that should be.. noticed by Cody thus this is unlikely